# Compiling an adjusted package in Windows

Tags: r, windows, package, rstudio, linear-programming

I am trying to create a package from an existed package called "rDEA". Basically, I have adjusted and added some functions to the source `.R` files and the DESCRIPTION file to include `Depends:`. However, when I checked the package I got the following `00install.out`:

```
* installing *source* package 'rDEA' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1  -DUSE_R=1 -I/include -DCHECK_GLPK_ARGS    -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c multi_glp_solve.c -o multi_glp_solve.o
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I/include -DCHECK_GLPK_ARGS    -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c     rDEA_initialize.c -o rDEA_initialize.o
gcc -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o rDEA.dll tmp.def multi_glp_solve.o rDEA_initialize.o -L/lib -lglpk -lgmp -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/i386 -lR
c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglpk
c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rDEA'
* removing 'C:/Users/Dell/Documents/rDEA.Rcheck/rDEA'
```

Here, it seems that the files `lglpk` and `lgmp` are not found when compiling. They are created from `Makevars.win` in the `src` as follows:`

```
#-*- Makefile -*-
#

PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I${GLPK_HOME}/include -DCHECK_GLPK_ARGS
PKG_LIBS=-L${GLPK_HOME}/lib -lglpk -lgmp
```

My questions are: How to solve this issue? Do I need to change directory?  Or do I need to use GSL (GNU Scientific Library) or other compilers? and how?

Please excuse my ignorance as I am no a computer scientist nor had good programming background.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!!